# Component is null after adding a conditional rendering in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm rendering my only component from App.js like so:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {gameState: "Menu"};
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {<MenuCanvas/> && this.state === {gameState: "Menu"}}
    </div>
  )
 }
}
```

and the Menu component looks like this

```
export default class MenuCanvas extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}

render() {

  return (
    <div>
      <canvas id="menu-canvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
    </div>
  )
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  startMenuLogic();
}
}
```

startMenuLogic() function, that is called in componentDidMount is a javascript function that currently only finds the canvas that's being rendered

```
canvas = document.getElementById('menu-canvas');
```

the problem is that the canvas is null, even though the function is called in componentDidMount, and the weird part is that the canvas was not null, until I added conditional rendering with state in the App.js. Before that my App.js simple returned  always, and everything was fine. What could be the problem and how could I fix this?

Comment: this.state === {gameState: "Menu"} is going to return false, as when you compare objects in JS they compare memory allocation space, not equality the way you are thinking about it. What you want is this.state.gameState === "Menu"

Comment: Exactly, it will never be true since you are creating a new object in the condition which means the references will not match.

Comment: I just noticed that and fixed it. Two of the answers bellow helped with the question problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditional rendering logic is wrong. The condition should be before the component:

```
      {this.state === {gameState: "Menu"} && <MenuCanvas/>}
```

So that if the condition is `false`, then `<MenuCanvas/>` isn't evaluated. That's the way [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) works:

`true && expression` returns `expression`, `false && expression` returns `false`.

Even then, as some comments have suggested already, the way you're comparing objects is not recommended since only references are compared. So your condition should be `this.state.gameState === "Menu"`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mistaken the sides:

```
{this.state.gameState === "Menu" && <MenuCanvas/>}
```